# when i run this code i get what is seem like encryption

Tags: php, sql

```
$result =mysqli_query($link, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo '<li>', $row['item_name'],  '</li>';
echo '<li>', $row['item_img'],  '</li>';
echo '<li>', $row['item_price'],  '</li>';
?>
```

when i run it i get the following: could same please explain the what is the problem and how to fix it

> ����JFIFHH��C       ��C  ���l"��   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B����    #3R�br� $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?���(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��(��l��rG�

Comment: `$row['item_img']` is an image, not a text...

Comment: could you please tell how to display image many thansk

Comment: I expect it is the `item_img` column. You need to show that separately, using its own HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

```
    echo '<li><img src=\"', $row['item_img'],  '\"/></li>';
```

As long as $row['item_img'] is the location of the image.

So change your database to hold the images location.

Comment: many thanks Nazca but could you please tell how to store the image location in database

Comment: I believe that deserves a separate question.  For the purposes of this question I suggest just changing your column to the location of the image.  For instance. http://gambit1204.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/ace_spades1.jpg

Then use the code I answered with.

Comment: heres a good link on how to insert data into a sql database
http://us3.php.net/pdo_mysql